# Android AWS Cognito: unable to resolve host

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-cognito

I am having difficulty getting Cognito registration and login to work for my app in Android Studio using [this sample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo). When I attempt to log in via the simulator, the app works for a few seconds, then displays an error message: "Unable to execute HTTP request: Unable to resolve host 'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com': No address associated with hostname". This same error is the only error that appears in the console. I have seen similar questions and tried solutions such as checking to ensure my app has the permissions `android.permission.INTERNET` and `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`, but the error persists. It also doesn't seem to be a network issue. I have updated to the latest version of the Android SDK as well as the AWS SDK, and the problem persists.

I currently I have a Cognito user pool set up which works properly for login on the iOS version of my app. Following the instructions in the readme for the sample code, I added an app to my existing user pool, and then copied and pasted the newly generated app client ID and app client secret into AppHelper.java for `clientId` and `clientSecret` respectively. I also set `userPoolId` to the ID listed for my user pool under "pool details" in the Cognito conosle, and `cognitoRegion` to US East, since this is the region of my user pool. I noticed that there was no need for me to set the pool name, as there was in the iOS version, so I'm wondering if that's something I need to do.

Sorry if this counts as a duplicate, but I wanted to post a question with the exact error message I encountered and the steps I took, and I'm wondering if someone has managed to get this specific sample working and what I should do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been resolved, but unfortunately I'm not quite sure what fixed it since I didn't change anything in the code. All I did was install an update, so anyone with a similar problem should probably ensure that all SDKs used in the sample are properly updated, along with the simulator. It's also worth noting that I was using a different network than in my previous tests, so it's possible that it was a network issue after all.

Comment: You didn't have internet

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

The issue occurred when I used a VPN with emulator to test my program. The reason was that the internet connection in the emulator was too slow when connecting through a VPN.

This could also happen if your internet connection is not strong enough.

The solution is, use a real android device to test your code, if your internet connection is not good enough.

More info: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/567